# Maps Pro working in Jasper Studio but not on IBM WAS Server

Tags: jasper-reports, jasperserver

I installed the TIBCO Jaspersoft Studio Professional - Visual Designer for JasperReports verion 6.0.1 30 Day Trial. I was able to create simple bar and pie chart and after compiling the jrxml into jasper i was also able to deploy them on IBM WAS Server, all of them worked like charm. But when i created chart using Maps Pro i was able to view it correctly in Preview but when i compiled it to jasper and deployed it to IBM WAS server it didn't worked.

In my view following was root cause:

```
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.jaspersoft.jasperreports.fusion.maps.StandardMapComponent from [Module "deployment.siperian-mrm.ear.zds-gui.war:main" from Service Module Loader].
```

Does in Trial version this doesn't work or i am doing something wrong, or need some classpath settings?

Following is the detail log for the error i am getting in server:

> 18:17:55,856 INFO  [stdout] (AsyncAppender-Dispatcher-Thread-144)
>   com.siperian.dsapp.domain.common.DomainLevelException: EXCEPTION||An
>   unexpected error occurred. 18:17:55,856 INFO  [stdout]
>   (AsyncAppender-Dispatcher-Thread-144)       at
>   com.siperian.dsapp.mde.domain.report.MDEReportService.generateReport(MDEReportService.java:70)
>   18:17:55,856 INFO  [stdout] (AsyncAppender-Dispatcher-Thread-144)
>   at
>   com.siperian.dsapp.mde.jsf.server.report.ReportHandler.handleRequest(ReportHandler.java:61)
>   18:17:55,856 INFO  [stdout] (AsyncAppender-Dispatcher-Thread-144)
>   at
>   org.springframework.web.context.support.HttpRequestHandlerServlet.service(HttpRequestHandlerServlet.java:63)
>   18:17:55,856 INFO  [stdout] (AsyncAppender-Dispatcher-Thread-144)
>   at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:847)
>   18:17:55,856 INFO  [stdout] (AsyncAppender-Dispatcher-Thread-144)
>   at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:295)
>   18:17:55,856 INFO  [stdout] (AsyncAppender-Dispatcher-Thread-144)
>   at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:214)
>   18:17:55,856 INFO  [stdout] (AsyncAppender-Dispatcher-Thread-144)
>   at
>   com.siperian.dsapp.jsf.server.security.AbstractSecurityFilter.doFilter(AbstractSecurityFilter.java:210)
>   18:17:55,856 INFO  [stdout] (AsyncAppender-Dispatcher-Thread-144)
>   at
>   com.siperian.dsapp.jsf.server.security.StandardSecurityFilter.doFilter(StandardSecurityFilter.java:112)
>   18:17:55,856 INFO  [stdout] (AsyncAppender-Dispatcher-Thread-144)
>   at
>   org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:236)
>   18:17:55,856 INFO  [stdout] (AsyncAppender-Dispatcher-Thread-144)
>   at
>   org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:167)
>   18:17:55,856 INFO  [stdout] (AsyncAppender-Dispatcher-Thread-144)
>   at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:246)
>   18:17:55,856 INFO  [stdout] (AsyncAppender-Dispatcher-Thread-144)
>   at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:214)
>   18:17:55,856 INFO  [stdout] (AsyncAppender-Dispatcher-Thread-144)
>   at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:231)
>   18:17:55,856 INFO  [stdout] (AsyncAppender-Dispatcher-Thread-144)
>   at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:149)
>   18:17:55,856 INFO  [stdout] (AsyncAppender-Dispatcher-Thread-144)
>   at
>   org.jboss.as.web.security.SecurityContextAssociationValve.invoke(SecurityContextAssociationValve.java:169)
>   18:17:55,856 INFO  [stdout] (AsyncAppender-Dispatcher-Thread-144)
>   at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:145)
>   18:17:55,856 INFO  [stdout] (AsyncAppender-Dispatcher-Thread-144)
>   at
>   org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:97)
>   18:17:55,856 INFO  [stdout] (AsyncAppender-Dispatcher-Thread-144)
>   at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:102)
>   18:17:55,856 INFO  [stdout] (AsyncAppender-Dispatcher-Thread-144)
>   at
>   org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:344)
>   18:17:55,866 INFO  [stdout] (AsyncAppender-Dispatcher-Thread-144)
>   at
>   org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:856)
>   18:17:55,866 INFO  [stdout] (AsyncAppender-Dispatcher-Thread-144)
>   at
>   org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:653)
>   18:17:55,866 INFO  [stdout] (AsyncAppender-Dispatcher-Thread-144)
>   at
>   org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:926)
>   18:17:55,866 INFO  [stdout] (AsyncAppender-Dispatcher-Thread-144)
>   at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) 18:17:55,866 INFO  [stdout]
>   (AsyncAppender-Dispatcher-Thread-144) Caused by:
>   com.siperian.dsapp.datasource.report.DBReportServiceException:
>   net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JRException: Class not found when loading
>   object from InputStream 18:17:55,866 INFO  [stdout]
>   (AsyncAppender-Dispatcher-Thread-144)       at
>   com.siperian.dsapp.datasource.report.DBReportService.generateReport(DBReportService.java:34)
>   18:17:55,866 INFO  [stdout] (AsyncAppender-Dispatcher-Thread-144)
>   at
>   com.siperian.dsapp.mde.domain.report.MDEReportService.generateReport(MDEReportService.java:68)
>   18:17:55,866 INFO  [stdout] (AsyncAppender-Dispatcher-Thread-144)
>   ... 22 more 18:17:55,866 INFO  [stdout]
>   (AsyncAppender-Dispatcher-Thread-144) Caused by:
>   net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JRException: Class not found when loading
>   object from InputStream 18:17:55,866 INFO  [stdout]
>   (AsyncAppender-Dispatcher-Thread-144)       at
>   net.sf.jasperreports.engine.util.JRLoader.loadObject(JRLoader.java:253)
>   18:17:55,866 INFO  [stdout] (AsyncAppender-Dispatcher-Thread-144)
>   at
>   net.sf.jasperreports.engine.util.JRLoader.loadObject(JRLoader.java:229)
>   18:17:55,866 INFO  [stdout] (AsyncAppender-Dispatcher-Thread-144)
>   at
>   net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JasperFillManager.fill(JasperFillManager.java:405)
>   18:17:55,866 INFO  [stdout] (AsyncAppender-Dispatcher-Thread-144)
>   at
>   net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JasperFillManager.fillReport(JasperFillManager.java:824)
>   18:17:55,866 INFO  [stdout] (AsyncAppender-Dispatcher-Thread-144)
>   at
>   com.siperian.dsapp.datasource.report.DBReportService.getJasperPrint(DBReportService.java:40)
>   18:17:55,866 INFO  [stdout] (AsyncAppender-Dispatcher-Thread-144)
>   at
>   com.siperian.dsapp.datasource.report.DBReportService.generateReport(DBReportService.java:25)
>   18:17:55,866 INFO  [stdout] (AsyncAppender-Dispatcher-Thread-144)
>   ... 23 more 18:17:55,866 INFO  [stdout]
>   (AsyncAppender-Dispatcher-Thread-144) Caused by:
>   java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:
>   com.jaspersoft.jasperreports.fusion.maps.StandardMapComponent from
>   [Module "deployment.siperian-mrm.ear.zds-gui.war:main" from Service
>   Module Loader] 18:17:55,866 INFO  [stdout]
>   (AsyncAppender-Dispatcher-Thread-144)       at
>   org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.findClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:213)
>   18:17:55,866 INFO  [stdout] (AsyncAppender-Dispatcher-Thread-144)
>   at
>   org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClassUnchecked(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:459)
>   18:17:55,866 INFO  [stdout] (AsyncAppender-Dispatcher-Thread-144)
>   at
>   org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClassChecked(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:408)
>   18:17:55,866 INFO  [stdout] (AsyncAppender-Dispatcher-Thread-144)
>   at
>   org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:389)
>   18:17:55,866 INFO  [stdout] (AsyncAppender-Dispatcher-Thread-144)
>   at
>   org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.loadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:134)
>   18:17:55,856 INFO  [stdout] (AsyncAppender-Dispatcher-Thread-144)
>   [2015-03-04 18:17:55,846] [http-/192.168.1.14:8080-5] [ERROR]
>   com.siperian.dsapp.mde.jsf.server.report.ReportHandler: SIP-49000

Following is the header in my jrxml:

```
<jasperReport xmlns="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/xsd/jasperreport.xsd" name="SupplierStateWiseMap" pageWidth="900" pageHeight="250" orientation="Landscape" columnWidth="900" leftMargin="0" rightMargin="0" topMargin="0" bottomMargin="0" uuid="88aacb86-d339-42d7-9586-69cebc5e763f">
```

Any help would be highly appreciated

Answer (score 0):

to me it appears related to missing required libraries for JasperReports PRO components. Fusion Charts/Widgets/Maps are with HTML5 charts part of the Jaspersoft Professional package.

I'm not sure how it is configured your server, but you should check to have the related jars + license information (even if trial) + jasperreports properties set.

Did you tried to test your reports into a test trial installation of JasperReports Server PRO ?

Regards,
Massimo.